# ASP.NET Dropdownlist on select EnableEventValidation error

Tags: asp.net, dropdown

Framework 4.5.2 I use webforms.This dropdown is in my masterpage.If I select any option it doesnt firing the event and it goes to error :

My master page :

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.master.cs"  Inherits="LandOfSport.UI.apps.mp.Home" %>
```

> Invalid postback or callback argument. In the page configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> event validation is enabled using. This feature is for security reasons, initially that handles postback or callback events originate from the server control verifies that the independent variables of them. If it's anything like the data is valid and expected, to save data to validate postback or callback ClientScriptManager.Use the registerforeventvalidation method.

Here is my dropdownlist :

```
   <asp:DropDownList runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ID="ddlLang" 
                                 CssClass="ddlLang" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLang_OnSelectedIndexChanged"  >
                                 <asp:ListItem Text="TR" Value="tr-TR"></asp:ListItem>
                                 <asp:ListItem Text="US" Value="en-US"></asp:ListItem>
                             </asp:DropDownList>
```

Here is my css :

```
 <style>
  .ddlLang {
      background-color: black;
      border-color: black;
  }
  .ddlLang option {
      background-color: white;
  }
</style>
```

And my event :

```
 protected void ddlLang_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["CurrentLang"] = ddlLang.SelectedValue;
    }
```

What is the problem here I dont want change my EnableEventValidation.

Comment: The code you posted worked fine and does not reproduce the issue you're reporting. You're getting Mac error on ViewState validation. Check out html in your browser. Is there only one form tag in rendered html page? Can you see hidden input field "__EVENTVALIDATION" ?

Comment: yes there is two <form> , one is inside of another form but only one is runat="server" is this the problem ?

Comment: if the one that is submitted doesn't have the hidden input then yes, it is.

Comment: You are right my friend I delete it and it works now :)) Thank you ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, I'm expanding what I've mentioned on comments. The error you were getting is ASP.Net failing to validate events. This is a security feature that ensures that post back actions only come from events allowed and created at the server. This restriction is intended to prevent your website to be hacked by spoofed post backs.

```
<form method="post" action="./WebForm1.aspx" id="form1">
    <!-- Html dropdown and other tags here... -->
    <input type="hidden"
       name="__EVENTVALIDATION"
       id="__EVENTVALIDATION"
       value="Z8V8I/94JbyXAGZJ9RlOKv56ns..." />
</form>
```

When using Master pages, sometimes resulting Html page can end up having more than one `form` tag (e.g. both Master and WebForm defines a form, so they end up nested in resulting html page). If the one that is submitted doesn't have hidden field for event validation and this feature is enabled then validation error comes up.